# Resolving LXD Storage and Interface Cleanup Challenges

Tags: networking, server, juju, maas, openstack

**Introduction:**
Greetings, LXD Community! We recently encountered some storage and interface cleanup challenges while deploying Charmed Kubernetes on a virtual machine. In this blog post, we'll walk you through the step-by-step process of resolving these issues and optimizing your LXD environment.

**Problem Statement:**
Our initial challenge was to free up storage space on the VM and clean up unnecessary LXD containers and networks. However, we faced difficulties while trying to delete the LXD network (lxdbr0) and encountered errors stating that the network was in use.

Answer (score 2):

> **Stop and Delete LXD Containers:**
>
> Use the following commands to stop and delete all LXD containers:
>
> ```
> lxc stop --all
> lxc delete <container-name>
> ```
>
> **Stop LXD and Network Services:**
>
> Stop the LXD service:
>
> ```
> sudo systemctl stop lxd
> ```
>
> Set the LXD bridge (lxdbr0) down:
>
> ```
> sudo ip link set dev lxdbr0 down
> ```
>
> Delete the LXD bridge:
>
> ```
> sudo brctl delbr lxdbr0
> ```
>
> **Remove LXD Network:**
>
> If you encounter errors while deleting the LXD network, ensure that
> all containers are stopped and deleted. If issues persist, consider
> rebooting the machine.
>
> ```
> lxc network delete lxdbr0
> ```
>
> **Reinstall LXD:**
>
> Reinstall LXD using snap if needed:
>
> ```
> sudo snap install lxd
> ```
>
> **Bootstrap Charmed Kubernetes:**
>
> Rebootstrap Charmed Kubernetes using Juju:
>
> ```
> sudo snap install juju --classic
> juju bootstrap localhost --verbose
> ```
>
> **Delete Old Storage Pool:**
>
> Identify the storage pool:
>
> ```
> lxc storage list
> Delete the storage pool:
>
> lxc storage delete <storage-pool-name>
> ```
>
> **Remove Unused Storage Files:**
>
> Navigate to the LXD storage pool directory and remove any residual
> files:
>
> ```
> cd /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/<storage-pool-name>/
> ```
>
> **Cleanup Completed:**
>
> Verify the cleanup:
>
> ```
> lxc storage list
> ```
>
> **Conclusion:**
>
> Following these steps should help you resolve storage and interface
> cleanup challenges in your LXD environment. Remember to adapt the
> commands to your specific setup, and feel free to reach out to the
> community for assistance if needed.
>
> Happy LXD container management!

<sup>Answer moved here from [OP's question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1498811/1).</sup>